# Can I create .mdl models using python?

Tags: python, model

I am supposed to create or at least assemble existing .mdl models using python.

Is that possible and if yes, could someone help me out.

I did some research, but didnt find anything helpful.

Comment: How would you do it without Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nik, I see in your other post that this is for a school project.  I don't know how much time you have, but the STK certification training online is free and would make sure you have the fundamentals.  If you want to jump right into the middle, this link is part way through the level 2 path and talks about working with Python integration with STK: https://help.agi.com/stk/index.htm#training/StartPython.htm

Regarding .mdl files in STK, those are described in the STK online help: https://help.agi.com/stk/#vo/models-01.htm?TocPath=How%2520to%2520Use%2520STK%257CVisualization%257C3D%2520Graphics%2520(Globe)%2520Window%257CUsing%2520Models%257CCreating%2520an%2520MDL%2520Model%257C_____0

You can make an object in mdl format by building up from 3D primitives (cylinders, cubes, sphere's etc.).  A full STK install usually has a treasure trove of mdl models you can use or study (mdl files are plain text).  My STK install has them at C:\Program Files\AGI\STK 12\STKData\VO\Models

The flow of programmatically interfacing with STK is something like this:

1. Connect to STK
2. Make a new scenario or attach to an open one
3. Add a new object (a satellite in your case I think you said in your other question)
4. There are properties for setting the 3D model (.mdl) where you provide the file path to the file.

If you've created scenarios and inserted objects in the STK UI, then you should recognize this flow.

There are a lot of examples in the online AGI help.  My local STK installation also came with a zip file at C:\Program Files\AGI\STK 12\CodeSamples\CodeSamples.zip which has subfolders for 6 different languages, including Python.

Comment: Hi Kevin, First of all thanks a lot for the detailed answer.
I did watch the tutorials, but it didn't get me too far.

I think your answer will help a lot.